# TinyMCE BBCode: Convert UL

Tags: tinymce, bbcode

I'm overpowered, maybe can't see the correct way to fix it.

Below my bbcode

```
function rep(re, str)
{
    s = s.replace(re, str);
};

//replace ul
rep(/<ul>(.*?)<\/ul>/gi,"[list]$1[/list]");

// replace li
rep(/<li>(.*?)<\/li>/gi,"[*]$1");
```

Test Text:

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
</ul>
```

Converted Result with BBCODE:

```
<ul>
    [*]one
    [*]two
</ul>
```

Expected result:

```
[list]
    [*]one
    [*]two
[/list]
```

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it. Posting to help others.

// lists

```
rep(/<ul>/gi,"[list]");
rep(/<\/ul>/gi,"[/list]");
rep(/<ol>/gi,"[list=ol]");
rep(/<\/ol>/gi,"[/list]");
rep(/<li>(.*?)<\/li>/gi,"[*]$1");
```